# which wallets/softwares utilize taproot capabilites?

Tags: multi-signature, taproot, p2tr, mast

this question is not about being able to pay/receive to taproot addresses as I know there's a list for that [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption). I'm curious to see if anyone knows about wallets/software that utilize taproot capabilities for multi-sig, lightning, MAST capabilites, etc..